# Why does my CSS file does not load? Electron js

Tags: html, css

Here is the error I get:
Everything works perfect without electron js and the path I entered was provided by VS code itself.

[image]

---

I'm using Electron js v16 and have to put my css files inside app folder.

Answer (score 2):

You're using absolute paths to reference your CSS files from your HTML. By doing this, it is attempting to get those CSS files from the root directory (e.g. "C:/"). Try using relative paths. As an example for your case:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a folder in your root called `css`. If you don't, remove the `/css/` part. Also, make sure the spelling is correct. Note that files are case-sensitive, so check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `./css/etc.` instead of `/css/etc`